# Is there any optimization possible for function to reverse the order of bytes in an int32?

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Someone I know was recently asked this question in a coding interview. They were asked to write a function `reverseBytes` below such that if you pass it `0xabcdef12` it'd output `0x12efcdab`.

They gave the following solution.

```
unsigned int reverseBytes (unsigned int x) {
  unsigned int ans = 0;
  ans = ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) |   ((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) |  ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8);   
  return res;
}
```

Are there any further ways to optimize it? One can of course not do the 1st and 3rd mask, but they'd still need to do at least 2 bitmask operations, 4 bitwise-shift, and 3 bitwise-or, is that correct?

According to them, interviewer was expecting further optimizations. I'm at loss to see that there could be further optimization possible. If so, what are they?

Comment: Use processor instruction for that

Comment: There's a bug - the last term should have `<<` instead of `>>`.

Comment: what processor instruction? can you give example? 
they were looking for handwritten code to do that. not an api or a built-in function.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for pointing it out. fixed the typo bug.

Comment: Oh, and a worse bug: `>>` has higher precedence than `&`.  I spent the last couple minutes racking my brains to figure out why gcc was compiling it into `return x;`.

Comment: And that it should operate on `uint32_t` or at least `unsigned`; otherwise reversing `128` causes signed integer overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah, thanks for pointing it out. while typing it i worried about that but didn't check. fixed. but the idea is that they wrote the correct code with this complexity with the right parantheses, but interviewer was still expecting some solid optimization, e.g. reducing masks or such even further than what I stated in OP.

Comment: Anyway, where I was hoping to get to after all of that: once the code is correct, gcc compiles it into a single reverse-bytes instruction on machines that have one.  Can't really optimize any more than that.

Comment: Initializing directly with the result instead of 0 would be a valid optimization, but I would guess that's not what you are looking for?

Comment: @NateEldredge understand the point about `unsigned`, i was being a bit careless in writing the OP as I was focused more on the key question, but they did ask as a `unsigned` argument and the interviewee also gave the correct functional result. also fixed in the op. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @paul yes they were looking for something else, and i see it's an optimization but not what they were looking for.

Comment: @JoeBlack there is no more efficient way if you allow compiler optimization.

Comment: Um even the corrected code doesn't do what you are describing. Instead of rearranging in blocks of 4 bits, you are rearranging in blocks of 8 bits. I mean it's easy to generalize...

Comment: @Paul byte swap. Byte is 8 bits. Not nibble swap

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland well he say he wants 0xabcdef12 -> 0x21fedcba. But his code does 0xabcdef12 -> 0x12efcdab.

Comment: I mean yes from the naming it's right. But then his example is wrong. Each hexadecimal represents 4 bit and not 8 bit.

Comment: @Paul order of bytes is in the question. I think that he does realize what it means and examples make no sense

Comment: Given that it is not guaranteed (either by the standard, or in practice), was the question assuming a 4-byte `unsigned`?   Is it mandatory to use bit-shift, or can you consider other options?    Can you assume particular target platforms/compilers, use of inline assembler, and use of dedicated machine instructions that do this?  What about compiler optimisation settings?

Comment: Get rid of `ans` and simply `return` the expression.  (That will also get rid of the bug relating to `ans` vs `res`.

Comment: @paul thanks for pointing out the incorrect example. The description was correct, reverse order of bytes, but the example wasn't. Fixed it. It should have been 0x12efcdab.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this function will not work and even compile. If I was interviewer you would have no chance to pass the test. There is a problem with operation priorities and one shift is in the wrong direction.

`int` is not the same as `int32_t`

```
uint32_t reverseBytes (int32_t y) {
  int32_t ans = 0;
  uint32_t x = y;
  ans = ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) |   ((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) |  ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8);   
  return ans;
}
```

And any optimizing compiler will convert it a single operation if it is available on the target system

https://godbolt.org/z/5fWbGT

you can use compiler-specific builtins like `uint32_t __builtin_bswap32 (uint32_t x)` which is most efficient for the particular architecture and is the same efficient despite the optimization level.

Comment: fixed it. please ignore them typos. the core question still remains in the OP.

Comment: please assume for platforms where int is 32 bits. the interviewer actually used uint32_t from what i'm told but the point is that interviewer wanted something more associated with reducing bit-masks and shifts which is what i focused on as the key question in the OP.

Comment: I'd bet a cup of coffee that whatever "clever optimization" the interviewer had in mind would actually prevent the compiler from recognizing the code as byte swap, and result in worse code.

Comment: @NateEldredge apparently use the latest version of the code (changed 17 minutes ago). I have modified the OP code to avoid UBs https://godbolt.org/z/ash9P8

Answer (score 2):

If you have a circular shift, start with a shift of 16.

```
abcdef12 -->
ef12abcd
```

If not, then

```
m = ((m << 16) & 0xffff0000) |
    ((m >> 16) & 0x0000ffff);
```

Then

```
m = ((m << 8) & 0xff00ff00) |
    ((m >> 8) & 0x00ff00ff);
```

This technique is barely worth doing for a mere 4 items.  In fact it may be slower due to the various steps other than those being counted.

That was 2 stages, where 2 = log2(4).

But for, say, swapping all 64 *bits* in a 64-bit word, it is quite fast.  This will take 6 stages (6 = log2(64)).  That is, 3 times the work for 16 times as many things being swapped.

Another possible optimization:  Note that, for example, 0xff00ff00 and 0x00ff00ff are inverses of each other.  If `&!` is readily available in the hardware, and if loading a constant is costly, then this could be faster than the above 2nd stage:

```
m = ((m << 8) &   0xff00ff00) |
    ((m >> 8) & ~ 0xff00ff00);
```

The compiler optimizer may be able to load only the one constant and use it twice.

Comment: are each of the 3 code samples above equivalent? or are the first 2 do the reverseByte function? it's kind of unclear to me. could you put the most optimal version you have for uint32 inside the function in OP?

Comment: if first two assignments to m together do the job, then it's still has 4 shifts, 4 masks, 2 ORs and 1 extra assignment over a version of code in OP that can have at most 2 bitmask operations, 4 bitwise-shift, and 3 bitwise-or and 1 assignment (not counting temporaries).

Comment: @JoeBlack - All of which leads to my comment about reversing 64 bits.  At some point, an algorithm fails to shine.  By that, I mean that the algorithm I present works nicely for a large number of items to reverse, but is not necessarily better at 2 or 4 items.  More bluntly, it was a poorly designed interview question.  To see what I mean, work out the shift/etc counts for reversing the bytes in `uint64_t`.  Do it 1 byte at a time (about 8 of each op) and my way (about 6 of each).

Comment: `! 0xff00ff00` is always zero. It is the **logical** not bitwise ***not***

Comment: @chqrlie - Thanks.  I haven't coded in C for 20 years.